# Stop third party application installation

Tags: blackberry

Is there is any alternate way to stop the third party application installation on blackberry device other than CodeModuleListner....Because it is not supported in OS 4.5 devices....Does any Interface or method available for 4.5 OS.

Or it is possible to stop the installation by changing IT policies.

Thanks in advance..